# How to definitively diagnose hissing in steering in my 1997 Mitsubishi Pajaro?

Tags: noise, steering, mitsubishi

I have a 1997 Mitsubishi Pajaro 5 Door with a 3.5L V6 [6G74](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsubishi_6G7_engine#6G74) engine.

I hear a hissing sound coming from the engine. You can really hear it in the passenger cab.

As soon as I touch the steering wheel and move even 1 degree to left or right the hissing sound comes on and stays for while.  I can hear it while I'm driving and also while I'm stopped at a traffic light.  This depends on how much I turn the wheel and then it stops.

One mechanic had the hydraulic tank emptied and cleaned. They also opened the steering pump and changed some parts, but no luck.

Due to my location, there is almost no way for me to buy a new pump. It will cost a lot to get so I want to be sure that the pump is my problem.

How do I diagnose this noise **before** I spend a lot of money for replacement parts?